# Mapping an array of functions over an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I often need to map a list of functions (processors) to several arrays(channels) of float data) so I have written a helper function...

```
const mapMany = function(processors, channels){
  processors.forEach( function(processor){
    channels = channels.map( (channel) => channel.map(processor) );
  });
  return channels;
};
```

This reads OK (to me at least!) but mapping an array of functions over another array seems like such a generic thing I can't help but wonder if it IS "a thing" already i.e. is there a better / built in / canonical way of implementing this "Map Many" type functionality and if so what is the proper name for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a better approach for implementing this. Don't use `forEach`!

```
function mapMany(processors, channels) {
    return processors.reduce((channels, processor) =>
        channels.map(channel => channel.map(processor))
    , channels);
}
```

But no, there is no builtin for this nor a canonical name for it. It's a quite specific function, which can however be trivially composed of the standard building blocks.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had already tried that but it turns out I had passed reduce it's parameters the wrong way round!

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for `compose`. It looks something like this:

```
const compose = function (...fns) {
    const rest = fns.reverse();
    const first = rest.shift();
    return function (...args) {
        return rest.reduce((acc, f)=>f.call(this, acc), first.apply(this, args));
    };
};
```

Now you can compose functions like this:

```
const stringDouble = compose(String, x=>x*2);
stringDouble("44"); //==> "88"

["22","33","44"].map(stringDouble);
//=> ["44", "66", "88"]
```

And in your case you can write your function like this:

```
const mapMany = function(processors, channels){
  // compose iterates from last to first so i apply reverse
  const fun = compose.apply(undefined, processors.reverse());
  return channels.map(fun);
};
```

The advantage over your own code and the other answer using `reduce` is that this does not make `processors.length` arrays in the process but just the one.

There are libraries that supplies `compose`. It's a common function in functional programming.

Other mapping functions like the ones in Underscore lets you set `this`. Then class methods will work as I pass `this` to the underlying functions as well.

Comment: `map(f) . map(g) = map(f . g)` is an important _and_ useful identity.

Comment: Thanks. That looks lovely. Coming from decades of imperative coding it might take me a while to grok it but I'm going to stare at it until I do!

Comment: @technicalbloke It's not that difficult. Basically `compose(a,b,c)` is the same as `(...args)=>a(b(c(...args)))` so it's just more general.

Answer (score 1):

So as Bergi points out it was simply reduce I was looking for, splitting it into two functions makes it much clearer...

```
const applySingleProcessor = function(channels, processor){
  return channels.map( channel => channel.map(processor) );
};

const applyMultipleProcessors = function(processors, channels) {
  return processors.reduce(applySingleProcessor, channels);
};
```

Yay simplicity!

Answer (score 0):

While I would normally use `.reduce()` as @Bergi did, just for a variety here is a simple recursive `.map()` solution without `.reduce()`;

```js
var channels = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8], [857,1453,1881,1071]],
  processors = [x => x+1, x => x*x, x => Math.sqrt(x), x => x-1],
     mapMany = (processors, channels) => processors.length ? (channels = channels.map(c => c.map(processors[0])),
                                                              mapMany(processors.slice(1),channels))
                                                           : channels;
console.log(mapMany(processors,channels));
```